# System workflow message tokens missing after recent Civi upgrade

Tags: civievent, system-workflow-messages

Event online receipt system workflow messages are missing values for many fields that were working reliably before recent Civi update.

Are there token changes that might be causing this?

Is there a way to find any errors for token problems?    Would one problem token cause all following tokens to fail?   (Values in earlier portion of message are being completed)

Comment: There were LOTS of token changes in 5.43+ although not specifically for the event receipt template. Which tokens?

Comment: Hard to say, there are a lot that represent custom fields and profiles using fields.

Comment: Is there any way to get a list of token syntax that is correct vs. those that might have been deprecated?

Comment: It's not that tokens were deprecated, it's that the underlying processing is different, and some smarty variables, e.g. `{$contact.X}` are replaced with a replacement `{contact.Y}` token. But something like `{contact.custom_12}` should still work.

Comment: So removing the $ might do the trick?

Comment: If the X and Y are the same yes. You might need to look in the tokens dropdown to get the right replacement if they're slightly different. Something like {$contact.contact_id} might now be {contact.id}